# Instantiate UIViewController using UITapGestureRecognizer on UIImageView

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to create an app that contains a list of thumbnail images that once touched creates a new view controller with one large UIImageView that displays the selected image from the thumbnail view controller. In the "SmallPicsViewController" I have the below code, however, when selecting the image nothing happens. The new view controller I am attempting to instantiate is called "BigPicsViewController" which contains an IBOutlet to a UIIMageView called bigPic.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
if([[touch valueForKey:@"view"]isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){

    UIImageView *viewSelected = (UIImageView *)[touch valueForKey:@"view"];

    BigPicsViewController *bigController = [[BigPicsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"BigPicsViewController" bundle:nil];

    bigController.bigPic = viewSelected;

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "nothing happens"? As the code appears above, you do nothing with the new view controller. You need to either push it onto a `UINavigationController` stack, or present as a modal view from the current view controller (I say "either" because I have no idea how your app UI flow is set up).

Answer (score 0):

Three possible reasons:

1)The `touchesBegan` method isn't called at all, most likely because `UIImageView` has `userInteractionEnabled` set to NO by default, which means it will not register touches.

2)The method is called, but, again, because `UIImageView` has `userInteractionEnabled` set to NO, a view underneath the image view registers it, so the if statement is false.

3)As gschandler said, you don't seem to do anything with the view controller that would make its view appear in the hierarchy.

Use breakpoints or log statements to figure out which it is.